# Django-oscar: Type Error following the tutorial

Tags: django, django-oscar

I'm following [the tutorial](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/internals/getting_started.html) of oscar 1.6 with Django, after the migration I tried to run the server and got this problem. I don't know what could be the issue to fix, I don't understand what it's telling me the Type Error and how to correct it. Any advice would be welcome

The Error:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 25, 2018 - 20:40:21
Django version 1.11.12, using settings 'frobshop.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f53a7ad29d8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scripts/oscar/shop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/scripts/oscar/shop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 146, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/home/scripts/oscar/shop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 28, in get_handler
    handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/home/scripts/oscar/shop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 67, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/scripts/oscar/shop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 47, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "/home/scripts/oscar/shop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/home/scripts/oscar/shop/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/scripts/oscar/frobshop/frobshop/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/home/scripts/oscar/shop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "/home/scripts/oscar/shop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/scripts/oscar/shop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for frobshop project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.12.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from oscar.defaults import *
from oscar import OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
from oscar import get_core_apps

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'u4qr6u*af63b3t#+0dkxar@cx4ok8dx4wu4&o_p@$!8nlh8mdg'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'compressor',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'django.contrib.sites',
] + get_core_apps()

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'frobshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.promotions.context_processors.promotions',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'frobshop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/solr/',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    },
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Thank you for reading me

Comment: what version of the django?

Comment: I missed sorry, it's Django 1.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added two invalid entries to your `MIDDLEWARE` setting:

```
'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
```

Both of those are not middleware, but authentication backends that should be added to an `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```